# Background Image with Linear Gradient

Tags: html, css

I have a couple questions about Linear Gradient:

Is it possible to have an actual image rather than colour display instead of either the `#000000` of `#ffffff`?

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, #000000 50%, #ffffff 50%);
```

Also would it be possible in the above example (which is black for 50% width then a 30 degree vertical split then white for 50%), so if the image replaced #000000, is it possible to place a border on the right hand of the image along the 30 degree divide that seperated the image  and colour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I got right what do you need, but here is an example.

```css
.gradient-image {
  width:128px;
  height:128px;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to right, 
  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, 
  rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%, 
  rgba(0,0,0,1) 61%, 
  rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%,
  rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 66%,
  rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%),
  url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXvxw.jpg?s=128&g=1);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-image"></div>
```

Comment: That's what I was wanting, so if the green was a solid colour would it be possible to have a border on it's left side between it and the image?